# Nest Javascript custom events

Tags: javascript

There are more custom onclick events on a page. I want for every custom onclick event to first prevent the default, do my things and then pass the command to the first custom event.

In other words I want to put my event on top of any other assigned click events. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7733425/1807643).

**OR**

Refering to [this explanation](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link4) you can choose where to get involved in the event-dispatching-process.

It states clearly

> In the browsers that support the W3C DOM, a traditional event registration
>   `element1.onclick = doSomething2;`
>   is seen as a registration in the bubbling phase.

So you have to hook into the capturing phase:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //do your stuff
},true);
```

This way your event is on top of other assigned click events.
But it is still a question, if the browser supports this kind of event handling.