# Have preventDefault() last for 200ms only - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, preventdefault

I have a link that I have set a preventDefault() method on, because I'm going to have a short animation on the link before it connects to the link address.

My problem is though I'm struggling how to set a preventDefault() to last for 200ms only.  I've tried using setTimeout(), but I didn't have any joy?

Basically in the code below I'd like it so that when someone clicks the anchor tag nothing happens for 200ms (I will actually have a fade out animation happen during these 200ms, but doing that is easy enough, it's just the timing on the preventDefault() that I'm struggling with).

CodePen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/BrRZbX

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  
  var link = document.getElementById("link");
  
  link.addEventListener("click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    
  })
  
});
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0; 
      display: flex; 
      justify-content: center; 
      align-items: center; 
      width: 100%; 
      height: 100vh;
     }
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com" id="link">Google</a>
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732854/is-there-a-universal-way-to-invoke-a-default-action-after-calling-event-preven) out, I think it may answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a way to `preventDefault` and then resume, but you should be able to navigate manually after a 200ms wait:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){

  var link = document.getElementById("link");

  link.addEventListener("click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     setTimeout(() => {
         // if you want to open in a new window
         window.open(e.target.href);
         // if you want to navigate away (same window)
         window.location = e.target.href;
     }, 200);
  })
});
```

Comment: He did want `target="_blank"` though, so he probably wants a new window.

Comment: No `target="blank"` isn't necessary, I only put that in so the link actually opened so to speak.  I didn't get to see your previous answer on how do it in the same window :(

Comment: I added it back, make sure to use only one of the two options though

Comment: Beware with the window.open: UAs will block it if it doesn't come from a trusted user event (like a click), and adding the timeout will make it out of this trusted event.

Comment: Neither of these work?  The delay happens for 200ms, and my small animation happens within this, but the link doesn't go to the `href="//localhost:8888/mysite/index.html"  The address displayed in the browser is  `localhost:8888/mysite/undefined` and i get a page not found error?

Comment: I updated it to use `e.target.href` instead of `this.href`. If that still doesn't work, check that the link has a valid URL that you could copy+paste to the address bar in your browser

Comment: Thanks @chameleon that works now.  When I said both answers weren't working I meant yours and the other persons. When it opened as a new window it did work in that context.  But thanks again for providing the solution to the secondary problem, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me:

```
e.preventDefault();
setTimeout(() => window.location = link.href, 200);
```

You can't really defer the `preventDefault` because it's synchronous - you'll have to force the default effect manually. (another option would be to create a custom event to dispatch to the element in 200ms, but that requires a lot more code)

Comment: Sorry I've made a mistake here, I shouldn't have put the target="blank" in.  How do I get it work in the same window?

Comment: This and the other person's answer don't work.  The delay happens for 200ms, and my small animation happens within this, but the link doesn't go to the `href="//localhost:8888/mysite/index.html"  The address displayed in the browser is  `localhost:8888/mysite/undefined` and i get a page not found error?

Comment: @TheChewy Whatever's causing that bug is outside of the code you've posted here. Presumably, whatever's generating your `href`s is not working properly.

Comment: No, your code was wrong.  It should have been `e.target.href`

Comment: I was assuming that your `var link = document.getElementById("link");` (as defined in the codepen) was the element you were looking for - in which case `link.href` would work - you'd only need `e.target` if your code was fundamentally different from what you actually posted.